# Can't execute wine runas

Tags: wine

I'm needing to run an .exe with normal user privileges (not as administrator). Wine by default runs as superuser, so the workaround is executing `C://system32/runas.exe` with the privileges provided for executing the program.

> $ wine runas
>   wine: cannot find L"C:\windows\system32\runas.exe"

however

> $ ls .wine/drive_c/windows/system32/runas.exe
>   .wine/drive_c/windows/system32/runas.exe

Comment: How did you install Wine?  I think you might need a *newer* Wine to make runas work properly

Comment: it's part of the leagueoflegends snap, but same happens with `apt install wine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"wine: cannot find L"C:\windows\system32\runas.exe"**

This seems to be Wine 5.0 Stable Branch (winehq-stable), however this branch have not all features (This problem have been answered on [r/wine_gaming](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/b56s2z/running_a_program_as_a_regular_windows_user/)), so you need install a brach witch supports that command. In this case, wine staging (winehq-staging) can execute the command your looking for.

**Install winehq-staging**

If you installed wine 5.0 succesfull, you can install winehq-staging by running:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

You can see more details of this command at [wine.org](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

Comment: I am unable to install winehq-staging as the system is unable to locate the package.  I am running wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1) on Ubuntu 20.04.